# Sort a 2D Array by Comparing Both the First and Second Integers using Java

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

The original 2D array is

```
int[][] array = {{4, 7}, {4, 1}, {14, 11}, {10 6}, {13, 4}, {4, 10}, {10, 3}, {9, 14}}
```

The above array should be sorted to the following:

```
int[][] array = {{4, 1}, {4, 7}, {4, 10}, {9, 14}, {10, 3}, {10 6}, {13, 4}, {14, 11}}
```

My code can sort based on only the first integer. how to do the sorting for the second one as well after the first integer has been sorted.

Comment: I think the answer is "the same way as first integer" but without seeing your code, it's quite difficult to answer

Comment: Why don't you show your code, so we can help you complete it?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know what your code does without seeing it but I believe what you are doing is using `Arrays.sort()` just as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949208/22748368), but to sort the way you want you must take a step further.

This worked for me:

```
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt((int[] a) -> a[0]).thenComparingInt(a -> a[1]));
```

So, basically what I'm doing here is sorting by the first dimension of the 2D array and then, once is sorted, sorte it again by the seccond dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Comparator` interface in Java to define a custom sorting logic
Refer the below code below :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TwoDimensionalArraySorting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = {{4, 7}, {4, 1}, {14, 11}, {10, 6}, {13, 4}, {4, 10}, {10, 3}, {9, 14}};
        sortIntArray(array);
        for (int[] row : array) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }

    public static void sortIntArray(int[][] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<int[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
                int compareFirst = Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]);
                return (compareFirst == 0) ? Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]) : compareFirst;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Refer the working code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/GmueBMLxfI)

Answer (score 0):

Using basic coding

1. Nested `for-loops`, whenever a sort is done on a collection of data you'll have to iterate and compare each element across all the others. So, the first loop starts with `i=0` and the inner loop starts with `j=i+1` because you don't have to compare elements in the same index.
2. Say that you are sorting in ascending order, so if the element at `i` is greater than `i+1` or if both are the same and the element at the second index is greater you need to swap them. Once an iteration is finished that index can be skipped for the next (that's why `j=i+1`).

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {

       for(int j=i+1; j<array.length; j++) {

           if(array[j][0] < array[i][0] ||
                   (array[j][0] == array[i][0] && array[j][1] < array[i][1])) {

               int[] temp = array[j];
               array[j] = array[i];
               array[i] = temp;
           }
       }
   }

   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
   ```